# ActionListener for a game with lots of buttons

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

So I am making a simple turn based Stradegy game with GUIS for a class project. I am quite new to GUIs and event driven programming, just as a heads up.

My main issue I am currently having is that I am using borderlayout with 225 TileButtons (buttons that extend Jbutton) in a 15x15 gridlayout, and i need to move a unit from one piece to another. I dont know how to use the action listener to get multiple buttons so what I'm currently doing is storing the (what I think is) tilebutton in an array nd when two buttons are pressed it will move the buttons. but I keep getting nullpointerexceptions.

this is my code for the action listener:

```
public class TileHandler implements ActionListener{
    public TileHandler(){

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if(moveMode){

            if(((TileButton)event.getSource()).getOccupied()){
                if(buttonPresses.isEmpty()){
                    buttonPresses.add((TileButton) event.getSource());
                    unitStats.setText("Unit Stats\n"+((TileButton) event.getSource()).getUnit().getStats());
                }else{
                    buttonPresses.add((TileButton)event.getSource());
                    buttonPresses.get(0).getUnit().move(buttonPresses.get(0),
                            buttonPresses.get(1),
                            buttonPresses.get(1).getTileLocation());
                    unitStats.setText("UNIT STATS");
                    buttonPresses.clear();
                    moveMode=false;
                    buttonActive=false;
                    defend.setEnabled(true);
                    attack.setEnabled(true);

                }
            }
        }
        if(attackMode){

        }
        if(defendMode){

        }else{

        }
    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us which line you are getting the null pointer exception at?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line: `buttonPresses.get(0).getUnit()....`, run in debug mode and see what buttonPresses contains.

Comment: @WorldBright I get the null pointer at `unitStats.setText("Unit Stats\n"+((TileButton) event.getSource()).getUnit().getStats());` @patterned I am not familiar with debugging or breakpoints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using a for loop like so.

```
for(TileButtons button: tilebuttons){ //an array holding all of the 225 tiles
    if(event.getSource()==button){
        //stuff
    }
}
```